# TortoiseSVN never runs post-commit.bat

Tags: tortoisesvn, trac, visualsvn-server, post-commit, svn-hooks

I have set up my subversion/trac environment on Windows (Now Win7, previously tried on Vista) and all works perfectly. But I can't get my post-commit to work.
Here's the setup (using VisualSVN and Trac running on Apache):

C:\Users\Martin\Repositories\test_svn\hooks:

**post-commit.bat:**

```
call %~dp0\trac-post-commit-hook.cmd %1 %2
```

**trac-post-commit-hook.cmd:**

```
@ECHO OFF
::
:: Trac post-commit-hook script for Windows
::
:: Contributed by markus, modified by cboos.

:: Usage:
::
:: 1) Insert the following line in your post-commit.bat script
::
:: call %~dp0\trac-post-commit-hook.cmd %1 %2
::
:: 2) Check the 'Modify paths' section below, be sure to set at least TRAC_ENV


:: ----------------------------------------------------------
:: Modify paths here:

:: -- this one *must* be set
SET TRAC_ENV=C:\Users\Martin\Trac\test_svn

:: -- set if Python is not in the system path
SET PYTHON_PATH=

:: -- set to the folder containing trac/ if installed in a non-standard location
SET TRAC_PATH=
:: ----------------------------------------------------------

:: Do not execute hook if trac environment does not exist
IF NOT EXIST %TRAC_ENV% GOTO :EOF

set PATH=%PYTHON_PATH%;%PATH%
set PYTHONPATH=%TRAC_PATH%;%PYTHONPATH%

SET REV=%2

Python "%~dp0\trac-post-commit-hook" -p "%TRAC_ENV%" -r "%REV%"
```

**trac-post-commit-hook:**

Grabbed from http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/branches/0.11-stable/contrib/trac-post-commit-hook

I have tested the scripts in a cmd window and they work all the way. But on a TortoiseSVN commit, nothing happens, which makes me believe that Tortoise never runs the post-commit.bat.

I have also tested a simple pre-commit, and that works.
The strange thing is that is HAS worked before, but I think I used an earlier release of VisualSVN then.

Does anyone have any idea on what's going on here?

Thanks a lot!
/Martin

Answer (score 2):

The post-commit hook is run server side.  If the hook is implemented correctly, it should work for any Subversion client.  You'll want to take a look at [this chapter](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks) from the SVN book.

Follow-up: You might take a look at [this](http://dancingpenguinsoflight.com/2009/01/updating-trac-tickets-in-svn-commits/) blog entry.

Comment: So what you're suggesting is that it is a permission problem? I have checked all permissions, but everything has SYSTEM, local user and Administrators has full control permissions. 
Thank you for taking time on this!

Comment: You can do client-side hook scripts with TortoiseSVN (now).